# Properly getting X and Y coordinates from a text file and plot the curve

Tags: c#

I have a tab-delimited file containing numbers in scientific notation in 2 separate columns (cf. picture). I need to properly read the file, store the first column as the X coordinates and the second to Y (after having converted the separated strings into double or float), and then plot Y as function of X (in my case power as function of frequency). I am new in C# and I have tried to follow previous posts unsuccessfully. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: You should post what you've tried.

Comment: This sounds like a better job for Excel.

Comment: Also, you should post the data (or a subset of it) as text instead of a picture.

Comment: You might consider taking the [tour] or reading [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (providing that the separator between columns is *tabulation* `\t`):

```
var data = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\test_.txt")
  .Skip(1)
  .Select(line => line.Split(new Char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .Select(chunk => chunk
    .Select(x => Double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray());

foreach (var pair in data) 
  myChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(pair[0], pair[1]);
```

Comment: I am having an error: "myChart" dosn't exist in the following context. How can I fix this? Is it also possible to make the X axis logarithmic and keep the Y linear?

Comment: @Ala: Add `Chart` on the form where you want to display the chart (`ToolBox` page, `Data` group `Chart` item); change its name into `myChart`; then edit `Series` - axis (logarithmic) kind (simple line, dots, spline etc.)

Comment: @ Dmitry: sorry, I haven't understood you. I currently have 2 ".cs" files. I added a form, right-clicked on its properties but I haven't found what you are talking about. Thank you for your patience with a programming newbye :)

Comment: @Ala: In Visual Studio open the form, open the tab (or window) `Toolbox` (do the same when you add, say, a `Button` on a form, but add `Chart` now). In the `ToolBox` you can find `Chart` in the `Data` group (while `Button` is in the `Common Controls` group)

Answer (score 0):

@ Dmitry: I have finally found this Toolbox, I had problems finding it as I am working with a French visual Studio. I did what you said but it is still not recognizing myChart.
Here is a screenshot of Visual Studio.
[Visual Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNorO.png)